# How to send `--files-from` with newline special character in rsync?

Tags: rsync

For some strange reason, there are people's directories with newlines in them, reproducible with something like:

```
mkdir normal
mv normal why$'\n'would$'\t'you$'\r'dothis
```

and I am responsible for rsyncing the files and folders containing these weird characters.

I am currently parallelizing my rsync, and so I need to recurse down a root directory and break the work into manageable chunks. The root directory does not have these crazy characters. Running `rsync --dry-run` gives me files that I can parallelize, but **for example the `\n` character becomes `\#012`**, which I suspect is octal.

However, when it's escaped like this, I can no longer send `rsync -a --files-from=files.txt` where `files.txt` contains this escaped `\#012` because rsync won't find this folder.

What should I do in this situation? Is there some extra escape step that I'm missing that can allow rsync to pick this up? I can't possibly write a `\n` because then the file:

```
somedumb\nthing
```

becomes

```
somedumb
thing
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `--from0` argument, which allows the sender to separate filenames with `\0`.

```
cd /source/path1 &&
    find . -print0 | rsync -av --files-from=- --from0 . remote:/target/
```

or

```
find /source/path1/./ -print0 | rsync -av --files-from=- --from0 / remote:/target/
```